# setting the limit in extjs store doesn't update the page variable

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have the following in my store. Note the limit is set to 10. I can see on firebug that 10 records are returned. My issue is that my grid pagination doesn't seems to have the correct "page" value.

ie i have 11 records in total ( which should be 2 pages )

```
proxy:{
    type:'ajax',
    api:{
        read: '/CutterHistory/Read/',
        update:'/CutterHistory/Update',
        create:'/CutterHistory/Update',
        destroy:'/CutterHistory/Remove'
    },
    reader:{
        type:'json',
        root:'CutterHistories',
        successProperty:'success',
        totalProperty:'Total'
    },
    writer:{
        type:'json',
        allowSingle:true
    },
    simpleSortMode: true,
    extraParams : {
        'sort' : sortBy,
        'search' : search,
        'limit' : 10,
        'destroyed' : destroyed
    }
},
```

[image]

and my grid

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to include `sort` and `limit` as extra params. If you have a paging toolbar, you should simply set the [pageSize](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-pageSize) in your store and the store will take care of all this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't need to include sort and limit as extra params. If you have a paging toolbar, you should simply set the [pageSize](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-pageSize) in your store and the store will take care of all this